# InvalidSyntaxException passing GraphQL query parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, graphql

Trying to implements the code to be able to execute the following graphql query:

```
query FIND_BY_BATCHID_LIMIT {
  findByBatchIdAndLimit(batch_id: 10, limit: 5) {
    id
    first_name
    last_name
  }
}
```

So the following implementation:

query.graphqls

```
type Query {
    findByBatchIdAndLimit(batch_id: Int!, limit: Int!): [RawEntity]
}
```

Repository and Query

```java
@Repository
public interface RawRepository extends JpaRepository<RawEntity, Integer> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM rawdata where batch_id = :batch_id LIMIT :limit", nativeQuery = true)
  List<RawEntity> findByBatchIdAndLimit(Integer batch_id, Integer limit);
}


@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
  @Autowired
  private RawRepository repository;
  public List<RawEntity> findByBatchIdAndLimit(Integer batch_id, Integer limit) {
    return repository.findByBatchIdAndLimit(batch_id, limit);
  }
}
```

But getting a:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is graphql.parser.InvalidSyntaxException: Invalid Syntax : offending token '!' at line 46 column 11
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 139 common frames omitted
Caused by: graphql.parser.InvalidSyntaxException: Invalid Syntax : offending token '!' at line 46 column 11
```

While the following finder implementation work:

query.graphqls

```
type Query {
    findByLimit(limit: Int!): [RawEntity]
}
```

Repository and Query

```java
@Repository
public interface RawRepository extends JpaRepository<RawEntity, Integer> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM rawdata LIMIT :limit", nativeQuery = true)
  List<RawEntity> findByLimit(Integer limit);
}


@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
  @Autowired
  private RawRepository repository;
  public List<RawEntity> findByLimit(Integer limit) {
    return repository.findByLimit(limit);
  }
}
```

```
query FIND_BY_LIMIT {
  findByLimit(limit: 5) {
    id
    first_name
    last_name
  }
}
```

So might be the way I'm passing the batch_id, limit params, but googling, sounds the way to pass params.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue came from the Voyager dependency:

pom.xml when the question was raised:

```xml
        <!--         GraphQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--         Voyager-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>voyager-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${voyager.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Working pom:

```xml
        <!--         GraphQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```